Django Scrapy TypeError: RepoSpider.start_requests() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
I'm trying to build a webapp to fetch data from a repo. It's near completion, but I am facing this error currently.
The codes:
This is the spider code
import scrapy
from App.models import Repo


class RepoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "RepoSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["github.com"]
    start_urls = []

    def start_requests(self, url):
        yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url
        url_parts = url.split('/')
        username = url_parts[-1]
        repo = url_parts[-2]

        description = response.css('.f4.my-3::text').get(default='').strip()
        language = response.css('.color-fg-default.text-bold.mr-1::text').get(default='')
        stars = response.css('a.Link.Link--muted strong::text').get(default='0').strip()

        yield {
            'username': username,
            'repo': repo,
            'description': description,
            'top_language': language,
            'stars': stars
        }

        scraped_repo = Repo(
            url=url,
            username=username,
            description=description,
            top_language=language,
            stars=stars
        )
        scraped_repo.save()

django view
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Repo
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from .tester.tester.spiders.repo import RepoSpider

def index(request):

    if request.method =='POST':
        url = request.POST.get('url')

        process = CrawlerProcess()
        process.crawl(RepoSpider, url)
        process.start()
    return render(request, 'index.html')

Tried whatever I could get on, but running out of options now. This is a project I need to get done as soon as possible, it would mean a lot to me to have this working.

def start_requests(self):         yield scrapy.Request(self.url)
do this

(Starting CrawlerProcess from a view won't work anyway so after you fix your start_requests error you'll need to rethink your architecture)

you can update the start_requests like following.
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(self.url)

